# How to colour only specific rows in a HTML Table created with Powershell

Tags: colors, rows

i would like to highlight some rows in my html table, simply changing the colour. I created 2 variations of the style ($style1 and style2) changing only the background color. But now i really don t know how to apply the second one. I need to do something like this:

```
if($array.TotalItemsize -lt $array.ProhibitSendQuota)
{
   $style = $style1
}
else { $style = $style2)
```

But if i use if else, o should also use foreach, and if i use foreach in my code below, i don t get a good table because the header is repeated at every cicle.

i send the $htmlFile to my department via email.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
$htmlFile = $array | Sort-Object DisplayName |
Select DisplayName, @{label="Total Item Size";expression={"$([math]::round($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() /1Gb, 2)) GB"}},
                    @{label="Issue Warning Quota";expression={"$([math]::round($_.IssueWarningQuota.Value.ToBytes() /1Gb, 2)) GB"}},
                    @{label="Prohibit Send Quota";expression={"$([math]::round($_.ProhibitSendQuota.Value.ToBytes() /1Gb, 2)) GB"}},
                    @{label="Prohibit Send Receive Quota";expression={"$([math]::round($_.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota.Value.ToBytes() /1Gb, 2)) GB"}} |
ConvertTo-Html -Head $style |  Out-File C:\Users\User1\Documents\test.html
Invoke-Expression C:\Users\User1\Documents\test.html
```